# Bash: sorting files according to their name

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a workdir filled with many *.dlg text files. The name of each file is given in the following format

```
7000_01_lig_cne_1000.dlg
1300_01_lig_cne_1000.dlg
5000_01_lig_cne_1000.dlg
6000_01_lig_cne_1000.dlg
```

I need to write some bash workflow to sort these filles accoridng to its first index (a number occured at the begining of the name, before the first _): 1300, 7000, 5000 or 6000, and create separate directory for each of the index and then copy it into it.
In this example I should have 4 different directories: 7000, 1300, 5000 and 6000 with one file into it. But then I will have to apply the script for huge filles with the naming different after the first _

It may be something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#set the name of folder with folles to be sorted
FILES=$PWD/test
# where output directories should be created
OUTPUT=$PWD
for i in ${FILES}/[0-9]*_*.dlg      
do 
    mkdir -p  ${OUTPUT}/${i%%_*}       
    cp $i ${OUTPUT}/${i%%_*}
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one that copies files from current working dir and makes the new dirs in the same place:

```
for i in [0-9]*_*.dlg        # define this better to suit your needs
do 
    mkdir -p  ${i%%_*}       # remove substring starting from the 1st _
    cp $i ${i%%_*}
done
```

If the files are in a separate dir:

```
for i in dir/[0-9]*_*dlg     # they are in dir or path
do 
    j=${i##*/}               # strip the path off from beginning to last /
    mkdir -p ${j%%_*}        # strip off from the first _ to the end
    cp $i ${j%%_*}
done
```

It will make dirs to current working directory.

Use quotes around variables if needed.

Comment: It produces very strange results :-) it creates a folder named scratch and put there ALL files found in DIR. I just changed the first string of your script to locate the filles:  for i in $PWD/test/[0-9]*_*.dlg

Comment: _define this better to suit your needs_ If the files are in a dir, that needs to be handles first. Gimme a sec.

Comment: I've just edited my first topic integrating my script with LOOP and you sollution. I don't see any problems to locate the files in the DIR. What may be wrong there? thank you !

Comment: yes! your second example perfectly matchs my problem! thank you again !

Answer (score -1):

Seems you want to arrange files via keywords, from your example:

```
mkdir 1300
cp 1300_01_lig_cne_1000.dlg 1300
mkdir 5000
cp 5000_01_lig_cne_1000.dlg 5000
mkdir 6000
cp 6000_01_lig_cne_1000.dlg 6000
mkdir 7000
cp 7000_01_lig_cne_1000.dlg 7000
```

If that is true, try below:

```
flist=()
for i in `ls`;
do
#folder name check
fname=`echo $i | cut -d '_' -f1;`
#if the file match no folder, create it
if [[ ! " ${flist[@]} " =~ " ${fname} " ]]; then
flist+=($fname)
echo "mkdir $fname" #do not remove echo unless you are sure
fi    
# if the file match the folder, copy or move it
if [[ " ${flist[@]} " =~ " ${fname} " ]]; then
echo "cp $i $fname" #do not remove echo unless you are sure
fi
done
```

Comment: Mandatory [Parsing `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) link. And also [about backticks](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: Yes you understand the task correctly, thank you ! sorry, I don't understand completely how it would be possible to specify in the beginning of the script, the name of the initial folder (containing all *.dlg) filles? for example, there is a folder DIR (with all dlg filles) and your script outside of this folder, I need to run the script in order to sort filles (present in DIR) and creating new folders OUTSIDE the DIR. Also within DIR there are many other filles, so I ought to set up the filter that I need to sort only *.dlg filles according to their names ...